# Cocktail mixing (shaking & straining) on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, food, melacha-creative-work, eating

Is one allowed to use a shaker to strain an alcoholic drink on Shabbos? I have been told that it is *mutar* to use a [pitcher with an ice guard](http://www.rubbermaid.com/Category/Pages/ProductDetail.aspx?spaceId=Kitchen%28RubbermaidSpaces%29&CatName=Beverage&SubcatId=BeverageStorage&Prod_ID=RP091194) on Shabbos, but I do not know the reason why this is not considered *borer;* the drinker clearly does not want the ice, which I would imagine gives the ice the status of *psoles*. Does anyone know the source for this *heter*, and whether it applies to using a shaker for cocktail mixing? Thanks!

Comment: eykanal, Welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for this excellent question! I've been wondering this myself, both about the pitcher and the shaker.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I think the reason why the ice-in-pitcher case is not a problem is because the ice cubes are big and identifiable in relation to the water they are in. One is permitted to remove a large carrot or matza ball from his bowl of chicken soup if it is undesirable to him. It is not considered *borer* to do so.

Comment: @jake, what about the fact that you're not cleanly separating the two (but are, rather, leaving water with the ice)?

Comment: @msh210, perhaps. But then one may not actually finish the pitcher of water.

Comment: Remember to always CYLOR

Comment: @tom - I actually did, but very informally (pretty *al regel achas* at a kiddush last shabbos), and he didn't know the answer off the top of his head. So, of course, instead of asking him during the week, here I am :)

Comment: @eykanal, I recommend that the next time you see your Rabbi, you discuss this again, this time armed with whatever sources and arguments are developed here.

Comment: just drink the vodka neat. keep the bottle in the freezer. follow with a chaser of chilled lemonade, orange or cranberry juice. better to remove oneself from the place of machlochet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borer is the purification of a mixture using methods reserved for storage, as opposed to eating.  For example, when you purify a mixture through removing the unwanted, that is a method that is normally used for storage, not eating.

When you remove the wanted substance from the unwanted with a "purifying instrument", like your pitcher, you have purified using an eating method with one exception:  "Purifying instruments" are used for storage, not eating.  But in halacha, you are deemed to have used that instrument only if it was practically functional.

The Rema ( [O.C. 319:10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=282))paskens that one may purify water from impurities using a strainer since most would drink the water with the impurities (with a possible exception to an istanis acc. to Biur Halacha).  Although I would assume manual removal of the impurities from the water would be borer, the instrument cannot be said to be functioning in a halachic sense since the water is already "pure".  (It's a fine split, but makes sense.)

Similarly, a posek told me that I may use a salad spinner o Shabbos for a different reason in addition to the Rema.  As a senif lehakel, R' Moshe held that a purifying instrument is specifically where it is doing a job which cannot be done manually.  The salad may be dried by waving it back and forth.  The same is true for the ice water.

In summary, this pitcher is not a functioning kli borer as implied by the halacha.

To answer your beverage question, you would have to post more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still worried. Everything I've seen has indicated that there are three separate criterion for *borer* to be allowed; (1) food from waste, (2) immediate use, (3) separation via hand (not instrument). See [here](http://www.shemayisrael.co.il/parsha/ostroff/archives/shabbos56.htm) and [here](http://halachafortoday.com/ARCHIVES39MelachosBORER.aspx). You focus on the "immediacy" aspect, but all must be addressed, from what I understands. The Rema you mention sounds very relevant, I'll have to check it out.

Comment: Regarding more detail, how much more do you want? A [cocktail shaker](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cocktail+shaker+open&view=detail&id=8EEA37AE1606895F3DEFE3CBEA249F7DFCE37BF2&first=0&FORM=IDFRIR) is used to chill a drink. It has three parts - cup, lid with strainer on top, and a cap. Pour drink into cup, add ice, cover with capped strainer, shake, remove cap, pour drink out of strainer (so ice remains inside).

Comment: Lastly - and I'm done now with the comments now, really :) - can you provide a source for the Rema?

Comment: I never mentioned immediacy.  I think you are looking at the trees and not the forest.  If a swimming pool area has a rule not to jump, the intent is not to restrict anyone whose feet pushes up a drop to "jump" into the pool.  The rule against jumping is an application of the broader rule of "no dangerous activity".  Your rules are applications of a broader melacha (explained in my first paragraph).  That is why meisir klippa is allowed even though it is "good from bad", it's not categorized storage-method purification, but as eating-method.

Comment: Similarly, an instrument has to function in its storage-method use to qualify as the melacha.

Comment: @eykanal, as far as the drink, if the ice were there, would most people drink it anyway?

Comment: I'm not an expert bartender, but I think with respect to mixed drinks, that's similar to asking whether people would eat their plate when having dinner :)  The ice isn't meant to be *part* of the drink, but rather just to cool it. I'm answering this way because the ice isn't supposed to be there any more than a toothpick is "part" of a hors d'oeuvres.

Comment: In the Rema's time, if a bar were serving your choice of water with impurities or water without, everyone would take the water w/o.  The question is- if the ice were there, would people opt not to drink it?  (btw, when I mentioned meisir klippa above, I meant "bad from good")

Comment: This bit always confuses me, i.e. I keep asking and forgetting the answer... but.. isn't straining normally where you allow the bad stuff out of the straner and what remains is the good stuff? Like sifting for gold?  so wouldn't this be the opposite?

Comment: There are strainers and strainer like devices which work in either way (good from bad or bad from good).  Panning for gold is a fine example of where the good stuff stays in the strainer.  A wine seive is an example of the reverse.  Interestingly enough, both versions are mentioned in Pirkei Avot 5 (the mishna about remembering and forgetting).

Comment: According to R' Ribiat's 39 Melachot, using a device that works as well as one's hand is considered by hand.  Assuming gentle shaking so that ice is in relatively large pieces, one could strain the drink through one's fingers.  Not sure that this always works, because I could strain pasta from its cooking water with my hands too (the fact that I'd burn my hands in the process is irrelevant here).